# Changing Firebase project of Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

After migrating my flutter application from one firebase project to another I am facing several problems. When I connected firebase to the flutter project that time firebase push notification was working smoothly.
But after changing the firebase project from mine one to another with google-services.json file and changing appId.
After that all going well except that notification being received on background and terminated state. But after click it does not redirect the user.
No error shows in the log. What could be the reason?